# How to access parent scope, if needed to?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm struggling with this. Rating is a directive from Angular Bootstrap which I don't control, I can define a controller, and I'm trying to serialize the rating through it, however I don't seem to be able to have access to the parent article. I'm new to AngularJS so this is probably the silliest question, but I was experimenting with `$scope.$parent`, which in does gives me access to an `article` property, but when I do `$scope.$parent.article` it returns undefined, there must be another way.

This is the markup in question:

```
<div class="article full" data-ng-model="article">
  <header class="page-header">
    <h4>{{article.title}}</h4>
    <div class="article-rating" rating ng-controller="RatingsCtrl" value="article.rating" max="5"></div>
  </header>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

This is the directive in question https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/rating/rating.js, and this is my attempt on getting something to work, which doesn't add too much context, but as requested:

```
angular.module("myApp")
  .controller("RatingsCtrl", ($scope) ->
    console.log $scope.$parent.article #=> undefined

    $scope.$watch 'value', (newVal, oldVal) ->
      console.log "newVal = #{newVal} oldVal=#{oldVal}"
      console.log $scope.$parent.article #=> undefined
  )
```

Comment: post your javascript please

Comment: I would not propose you to try getting parent's scope. Think about people that would maintain your code. If you need any info from parents scope, pass the variables, pass config objects, pass everything. why should child manipulate by parent ?

Comment: Ok guys, but how do I get access to article in the controller then? I need to be able to watch on the directive's bound "value" for rating, and then serialize that by including article's id and the given rating, how would you do that?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm having this exact problem right now and can't figure out why I can access the parent scope but not its nested attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see the script to reply more precisely, but you said that `$scope.parent` has an `article` property, but `$scope.$parent.article` is undefined.

If that's not a typo, you should use `$scope.parent.article` instead...

Comment: I meant $scope.$parent in both situations. If I console.log $scope.$parent I get an object dump which includes an article property, if I expand that I can effectively see the articles' properties such as body and id, but when I do $scope.$parent.article on it from any code, I get undefined as a response.

Comment: I edited the OP to avoid confusion, it's $scope.$parent everywhere and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me `article` is available in the current scope even though it's set in the parent scope.